# How to select individuals using a condition applyed on several rows?

Tags: r

Good morning,

I am currently working on animal body condition score (BCS). For each individual, I have several rows but not the same number of row from one to another. As columns I have the animal name (factor), the date (factor) when the BCS was recorded and BCS (numeric) itself.

There is an exemple of my data:

```
structure(list(name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("INDIV1", 
"INDIV2", "INDIV3", "INDIV4", "INDIV5", "INDIV6", 
"INDIV7", "INDIV8", "INDIV9", "INDIV10", 
"INDIV11", "INDIV12", "INDIV13", "INDIV14", "INDIV15", 
"INDIV16", "INDIV17", "INDIV18", "INDIV19", 
"INDIV20", "INDIV21", "INDIV22", "INDIV23", 
"INDIV24", "INDIV25", "INDIV26", "INDIV27", 
"INDIV28", "INDIV29", "INDIV30", "INDIV31", 
"INDIV32", "INDIV33", "INDIV34", "INDIV35", 
"INDIV36", "INDIV37", "INDIV38", "INDIV39", "INDIV40", 
"INDIV41", "INDIV42", "INDIV43", "INDIV44", "INDIV45", 
"INDIV46", "INDIV47", "INDIV48", "INDIV49", 
"INDIV50", "INDIV51", "INDIV52", "INDIV53", 
"INDIV54", "INDIV55", "INDIV56", "INDIV57", "INDIV58", 
"INDIV59", "INDIV60", "INDIV61", "INDIV62", 
"INDIV63", "INDIV64", "INDIV65", "INDIV66", 
"INDIV67", "INDIV68", "INDIV69", "INDIV70", 
"INDIV71", "INDIV72", "INDIV73", "INDIV74", 
"INDIV75", "INDIV76", "INDIV77", "INDIV78", "INDIV79", 
"INDIV80", "INDIV81", "INDIV82", "INDIV83", 
"INDIV84", "INDIV85", "INDIV86", "INDIV87", 
"INDIV88", "INDIV89", "INDIV90", 
"INDIV91", "INDIV92", "INDIV93", "INDIV94", 
"INDIV95", "INDIV96", "INDIV97", "INDIV98", 
"INDIV99", "INDIV100", "INDIV101", "INDIV102", "INDIV103", 
"INDIV104", "INDIV105", "INDIV106", "INDIV107", "INDIV108", 
"INDIV109", "INDIV110", "INDIV111", "INDIV112", 
"INDIV113", "INDIV114", "INDIV115", "INDIV116", 
"INDIV117", "INDIV118"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("03/10/2019", "03/12/2019", "04/12/2019", 
"05/02/2019", "06/02/2019", "07/04/2019", "08/01/2019", "10/04/2019", 
"10/12/2019", "11/02/2019", "11/09/2019", "11/12/2019", "12/08/2019", 
"12/09/2019", "12/12/2019", "13/02/2019", "13/03/2019", "13/08/2019", 
"13/09/2019", "14/05/2019", "14/06/2019", "14/11/2019", "15/07/2019", 
"15/10/2019", "15/11/2019", "16/01/2019", "16/04/2019", "16/07/2019", 
"16/10/2019", "17/05/2019", "18/06/2019", "18/10/2019", "19/03/2019", 
"19/06/2019", "19/12/2019", "20/03/2019", "21/03/2019", "23/07/2019", 
"25/04/2019", "26/04/2019", "27/09/2019", "28/01/2019", "28/05/2019", 
"28/06/2019", "31/05/2019"), class = "factor"), BCS = c(4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4.75, 4.75, 4.75, 4.75, 4.75, 4.75, 4.5, 
4.5, 4.5, 2.25, 2.25)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

My goal here, is to identify individuals with a BCS >= 4 for each measurement.

I have tried to make up functions using if and while statements but, so far, I can't get the information I am looking for...

I apologize in advance if this kind of question have been asked previously.

Thank you for your futur help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I named the data frame you provided df, so try:

```
df = droplevels(df)
tapply(df$BCS>=4,df$name,all)
INDIV1 INDIV2 
  TRUE  FALSE
```

The step above takes makes a boolean out of each BCS value, if >=4 it becomes TRUE, and then tapply splits this boolean according to name, and you ask whether all is true using `all`.

From the result above, it means INDIV1 has all BCS>=4

To get the names, do:

```
names(which(tapply(df$BCS>=4,df$name,all)))
[1] "INDIV1"
```

Comment: I also tried the code you shared and it also works perfectly well! Thank you a lot. However, I still have a small question, what is the point of the droplevels there?

Comment: Yes. In the example you provided, name is a factor, class(df$name). Factors contain something called levels that allows you to order or keep track of them, see levels(df$name).

Comment: droplevels on a data.frame or vector will drop levels that don't exist anymore on the data.frame. So that when you do tapply or table, these levels will not come up. You can try it with the df you provided, if you don't droplevels.

Comment: Thanks you very much for the extra explanation!

Comment: No problem :) Hope it make sense

Answer (score 1):

Not very clear about your objective by

> to identify individuals with a BCS >= 4 for each measurement

Maybe something like below is your desired output

```
> aggregate(BCS~name,df, FUN = function(x) all(x>=4))
    name   BCS
1 INDIV1  TRUE
2 INDIV2 FALSE
```

Comment: An animal with a BCS >= 4 all over the year may be considered as obese. I am currently trying to find out if there is any obese individual in the studied population.

The code above works perfectly, thank you a lot! I am always looking for too complicated solutions...

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(name) %>% 
   summarise(BCS = all(BCS >= 4))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  name   BCS  
#  <fct>  <lgl>
#1 INDIV1 TRUE 
#2 INDIV2 FALSE
```